# How to penalize gaps between days in OptaPlanner constraint stream?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I have a model where each `Course` has a list of available `TimeSlot`s from which one `TimeSlot` gets selected by OptaPlanner. Each `TimeSlot` has a `dayOfWeek` property. The weeks are numbered from 1 starting with Monday.

Let's say the `TimeSlot`s are allocated such that they occupy days 1, 3, and 5. This should be penalized by 2 since there's one free day between Monday and Wednesday, and one free day between Wednesday and Friday. By using `groupBy(course -> course.getSelectedTimeslot().getDayOfWeek().getValue())`, we can get a list of occupied days.

One idea is to use a collector like `sum()`, for example, and write something like `sum((day1, day2) -> day2 - day1 - 1)`, but `sum()`, of course, works with only one argument. But generally, maybe this could be done by using a custom constraint collector, however, I do not know whether these collectors can perform such a specific action.

Another idea is that instead of summing up the differences directly, we could simply map each consecutive pair of days (assuming they're ordered) to the difference with the upcoming one. Penalization with the weight of value would then perform the summing for us. For example, `1, 4, 5` would map onto `2, 0`, and we could then penalize for each item with the weight of its value.

If I had the weeks in an array, the code would look like this:

```
public static int penalize(int[] weeks) {
    Arrays.sort(weeks);

    int sumOfDifferences = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < weeks.length; i++) {
        sumOfDifferences += weeks[i] - weeks[i - 1] - 1;
    }

    return sumOfDifferences;
}
```

How can we perform penalization of gaps between days using constraint collectors?

Answer (score 1):

An approach using a constraint collector is certainly possible, see `ExperimentalCollectors` in `optaplanner-examples` module, and its use in the Nurse Rostering example.

However, for this case, I think that would be an overkill. Instead, think about "two days with a gap inbetween" as "two days at least 1 day apart, with no day inbetween". Once you reformulate your problem like that, `ifNotExists(...)` is your friend.

```
forEachUniquePair(Timeslot.class,
    Joiner.greaterThan(slot -> slot.dayOfWeek + 1))
    .ifNotExists(Timeslot.class,
         Joiners.lessThan((slot1, slot2) -> slot1.dayOfWeek, TimeSlot::dayOfWeek),
         Joiners.greaterThan((slot1, slot2) -> slot2.dayOfWeek, TimeSlot::dayOfWeek))
...
```

Obviously this is just pseudo-code, you will have to adapt it to your particular situation, but it should give you an idea for how to approach the problem.

Comment: Isn't this suboptimal? My proposal is in O(n log(n)), so checking each unique pair is much slower. Is there any way of making it faster? I mean, you could just sort the days and do one iteration, but I don't know how to achieve that with constraint streams.

Comment: Technically it would be suboptimal, but CS is incremental. It will only re-evaluate the timeslots that either changed, were added or removed. If you insist to do it your way, you certainly can with groupBy and a custom constraint collector, but my bet is that it will be slower.

Comment: Are the `ExperimentalConstraintCollectors` safe to use in production? I managed to find a hacky way of penalizing gaps by:

`.groupBy(ExperimentalConstraintCollectors.consecutiveTemporalIntervals(
                        e->LocalTime.of(0, e.getSelectedTimeslot().getDayOfWeek().getValue()),
                        e->LocalTime.of(0, e.getSelectedTimeslot().getDayOfWeek().getValue())))
                .flattenLast(ConsecutiveIntervalInfo::getBreaks)
                .penalize("",HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, e->(int)e.getLength().toMinutes() - 1);`

Or is there a better collector choice?

Comment: They are experimental as we are still looking for user feedback on them. As far as we know, they are safe, but we do not want to make them a fully supported API until we've heard people's opinions on the API.

Comment: Would you please look at my collector implementation in the second answer to this question? I presume you didn't intend your users to write their own collectors as I haven't been able to find any material on the topic. Nevertheless, I infered the functionality from the source code - the second argument returns a function that does the opposite of what the accumulator body does, right? Lastly, is it ok to use a Set object in the result container? I saw that you sometimes used a non-primitive, but didn't find anything special about the classes.

Comment: I finally tried the code you wrote and it doesn't seem to do anything useful. When I give it three consecutive days, it penlizes by two and when I give it Monday, Wednesday, and Friday, it penalizes by one.